# Cron jobs and Crontab -e not working after setting default editor

Tags: unix, vim, ubuntu-14.04, cron

I am logging into a aws instance using ubuntu 14.04. After I set the wrong default editor for cron, now cron -e cannot open, I need to use the below command to change the editor.

```
export EDITOR=vi
```

However when I log out and log back in, I need to do this again. Is there anyway to set the default editor to vim or some other editor. The below is what I get when I try to do it now.

```
crontab -e
937
```

I also tried to purge cron and reinstall it and still the same issue. Also cron itself is not working, I have a job set to run every minute and it just is not working.

Comment: How did you set the editor for cron in the first place? Set the variable in your shell startup scripts if you need it to persist.

Comment: It asked me when I first opened up crontab editor what the default editor should be. Now it just opens that

Comment: Also, how exactly do I setup the crontab default editor in my startup script?

Comment: I think you should put `export EDITOR=vi` into your `~/.profile`.

Comment: You put that `export` line in them to set that at shell session startup. That said you should probably find out where cron/crontab stored the incorrect setting and fix that instead. Look in `/etc` and/or see if there's an argument to crontab to change it.

Comment: Only arguments are this:

usage: crontab [-u user] file
 crontab [ -u user ] [ -i ] { -e | -l | -r }
  (default operation is replace, per 1003.2)
 -e (edit user's crontab)
 -l (list user's crontab)
 -r (delete user's crontab)
 -i (prompt before deleting user's crontab)

Comment: I also see a crontab file but nothing really useful in there

# /etc/crontab: system-wide crontab
# Unlike any other crontab you don't have to run the `crontab'
# command to install the new version when you edit this file
# and files in /etc/cron.d. These files also have username fields,
# that none of the other crontabs do.

SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

# m h dom mon dow user  command
17 *    * * *   root    cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly
...

Comment: Have you tried my suggestion mentioned before? Does it do anything?

Comment: It does work when I add that to the .profile file. Thank you for that. I guess now just trying to figure out why it doesn't run cron jobs from there. But that should be another question